# Can Runic blocks appear while "On Fire"?

Tags: pickcrafter

The "On Fire" mode makes you break Blocks instantly. I really worry that if a Runic Block appears, I'll miss the opportunity to multiply it.
**Can they spawn while the player is "On Fire?"**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, Runic blocks can appear during "On Fire".

Edit: Runic blocks no longer appear as a block wall, during any time.

Comment: Would they break instantly if so?

Comment: Yes, they would also break instantly like other blocks.